# Copy and paste is unwantedly changing opacity of objects in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, opacity

I've just started encountering a problem with Inkscape (version 0.48.4 installed on Ubuntu) where if I copy and paste an object (basically an opaque rectangle with overlaid text), the new copy of the object has reduced opacity, usually around 90%. It either changes the 'A' slider or the 'Opacity, %' slider, under Fill > HSL menu.

It's really frustrating as I'm making a fairly large and intricate flow diagram and keep realising objects are transparent so have to keep going back and changing each object individually.

Anyone know how I can fix this? I've tried uninstalling and re-installing inkscape but the problem persists.

Edit: I've just noticed that on the command line it's printing several of these kind of warnings that perhaps have something to do with it?

** (inkscape:27264): WARNING **: 549812304 bytes requested for pixel buffer, I won't try to allocate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, version 0.48 is quite old, and it may be a good idea to move on.

Have you checked whether it is actually the rectangle which has changed opacity? When several objects are selected, it is the average opacity which is displayed. Unselect all and re-select the rectangle only to check this (if in a group, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click to select the rectangle only).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, I'll try a newer version. I've since started new projects and don't have the same problem, I think it's something that just went wrong with that particular file I was working on.

Comment: I have this problem in Windows, too, with version 0.92.  When I select an object, (say a simple square) and use ctrl+c to copy it as a bitmap to the clipboard, and paste it into another application, say Krita, it has an opaque background.  I can't paste into InDesign at all.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: @bgmCoder: your question sounds different from the original one, you should post it independently.